# easyphp - phpmyadmin does not connect to mysql server

Tags: phpmyadmin, easyphp

I just installed easy php and the phpmyadmin does not connect to the mysql server. It throws an error which says - #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.

I have not done any setting or any sort of changes. I just installed and tried to open phpmyadmin. The config file looks like this -

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|phpmyadmin)';

/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

This is really annoying .. can someone help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Is PHP and MySQL on the same server?

Comment: i installed the whole package of easyphp into same folder ..no other changes i made. So i guess they should be on same server

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. And here's my workaround: download and install MySQL server, stop MySQL server service and use MySQL Workbench to control installed MySQL server with EasyPHP.